# Bash while sed is not null

Tags: bash, sed

I need to do while loop when sed is not null. Example:

File 1

```
line1
line2
line3
```

File 2

```
i=1

while sed "${int}p" # here I need expression which checks if line is not null
# here echo this line and i++
```

I tried to write just `while sed -n "${int}p"` but it does not work as I expected.

Comment: What do you mean by “a line is not null”? Do you mean an empty line? A line that contains only whitespace? Something else?

Comment: line which does not exist in a file :) not even newline character

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? Please define 'line', pay special attention the the role of linebreaks.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's still not at all clear what you're trying to do or what your question is.

Comment: I want to make a loop where n-th line goes into string variable, and it repeats until end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `=` command in sed to get the number of lines:

```
 sed -n '/./!q;=;p' input | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

For an input:

```
a
b
c

d
```

This gives:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

If you only want to get line number of the line before the first non-empty line:

```
sed -n '/./!q;=' input | tail -1
```

A while loop that prints all lines:

```
while read line; do
        echo "$line"
done < input
```

Comment: thanks, it partially solves problem; counting all lines in a file would be a solution, but I need to repeat n-th line to string and then increment n, from beginning to end of file.

Comment: what is your actual goal? do you want to get all numbers of non-empty lines?

Comment: noo:) I want to get all lines line by line to a variable, beginning from first line and finishing on last line. If file consists of 3 lines (and after these 3 lines is end of file) I need to get these 3 lines to variable (overwriting this variable), and then finish loop on end of file.

Comment: and how does this relate to null lines?

Comment: if line does not exist (ex. line number 4 if file has 3 lines), it is null, isn't it?:) I need to go until I arrive end of file.

Comment: is the edited part, the last while loop, in the answer what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that is it, accept and +1 from me. :) is it possible to assign read line to a variable?

Comment: In the example loop above each line is assigned to the variable `line`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the lines until the first empty line, you could do this.

```
$  cat in.txt 
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5
$ echo $(($(sed '/^\s*$/q' < in.txt | wc -l) - 1))
3
```